# Base class constructor not running

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, c-preprocessor

```
#define CLASS(ID) class ID{ \
    public: \
            ID(int) { cout<<#ID <<"\tconstructor"<<endl; } \
           ~ID(){cout<<#ID<<"\tDestroyed  "<<endl;} \
};
CLASS(Base);
CLASS(Member);

class Derived : public Base {
    public:
        Member *mem;
        Derived(int x) : Base(1) {
            cout<<"Derived constructor"<<endl;
            mem=new Member(2);
        }
        ~Derived()
        {
            cout<<"Derived Destroyed"<<endl;
            delete mem;
        }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    Derived * der=new Derived(1);
    cout<<"****"<<endl;
    delete der;
}
```

The output for this is:

```
Derived constructor
Member  constructor
****
Derived Destroyed
Member  Destroyed  
Base    Destroyed
```

In the second version :

```
class Derived : public Base {
    public:
        Member *mem;
        Derived(int x) : Base(1) {
            cout<<"Derived constructor"<<endl;
        }

        ~Derived()
        {
            cout<<"Derived Destroyed"<<endl;
            delete mem;
        }
};
```

Why in the first version the Base constructor don't executes when an instance from the same class has been instantiated?

Comment: Why this bizarre indentation style?

Comment: No, it most certainly is not.

Comment: What compiler are you using?  I just copied and pasted your code into Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 and the `Base` constructor is executed in the first case.

Comment: VS2010, Output is as expected (`Base constructor` is shown first).

Comment: Please post your real code: http://ideone.com/z8zch

Comment: Why downvotes? This behavior is abnormal. Yes... it's more probable he didn't post real code than he found a compiler bug, but... give him the benefit of the doubt!

Comment: @AlessandroPezzato: downvotes because the question is unanswerable, since we don't know what he did.

Comment: Mr Tomalak if u dont have an answer dont participate please it is a very good question. Mr duck the code answer you

Comment: @HusseinX, Tomalak is free to participate as he sees fit within the constraints of the SO guidelines.  He has given his views *in the comments* section and not as an answer.  This is what comments are *for*.  Commenting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On GCC version 4.6 I got this

```
Base    constructor
Derived constructor
Member  constructor
****
Derived Destroyed
Member  Destroyed  
Base    Destroyed
```

So it seems to be working

On a side note your base destructor should be virtual

```
 virtual ~ID(){}
```

this way when you only have a reference to the base you derived will still cleanly be removed.

On a side note, please don't use defines like this unless you have too, also wrapping up mem in a smart point is also a good idea. Like auto_ptr in c++98 (ideally the boost ptrs) or unique_ptr in c++11.

Comment: It is the best possible answer given that nobody knows what the question is.